# Is $\left<ad-bc,a+d\right>\subseteq k[a,b,c,d]$ a reduced ideal, and if yes, why?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Is $\left<ad-bc,a+d\right>\subseteq k[a,b,c,d]$ a reduced ideal, and if yes, why?

I have tried to prove it, but I have so far failed. The locus of this ideal can be identified with the $2\times 2$ matrices with only $0$s as eigenvalues.

Comment: "reduced" is a highly overloaded term so you should say what it means here.

Comment: You can observe that $k[a,b,c,d]/(ad-bc,a+d)\cong k[a,b,c]/(a^2+bc)$.